# LogCat: Unable to open log device

Tags: eclipse, logcat, galaxy

My Phone: Samsung Galaxy Note N7000
Kernel: HyDraCore_v6.2_B3_R3P0
Build: MIUI-2.10.19 RocketMIUI v8

I read many threads about that but nothing solved my problem...
When I connect my phone to my computer and run the project wirh "Run As -> Android Application" the program starts on my phone but the logcat is empty in eclipse :-/
In logcat I only receive this one message:

```
Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

[image]

What do I have to do to get it worked??

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Slim Rom (4.2.2, build 5) mod and they have disabled logging by default. 
What you have to to is to go to `/res/script` directory on your device and find relevant script for enablig log. In my case it's `S30enable_logger`. For your custom rom the scripts can have different naming convention (or directory) - consider checking it with your custom rom id.

So, given that  you are connected to your device via `adb` type in your pc terminal :

```
adb shell 
cd /res/scripts
./S30enable_logger
```

Then just reboot your device and log should work finally.