# Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory on my Nexus 4

Tags: android, logging, device, program-entry-point

As you can see my problem is : Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory . The application i'm writing i'm testing on my nexus 4. How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176437/logcat-unable-to-open-log-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jelly Bean Google prevented arbitrary apps from accessing the system/app logs so unless your device is rooted you won't be able to access the log file, either.

See http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html.

In order to allow on-device access of logs I created a Logger class that I use for all my debug logs.  It basically wraps android.util.Log, outputting all the Logger.d calls to Log.d and to a file in the root directory.  It doesn't yet output all the information contained in the Android logs, but you can edit it to put whatever info you'd like in there.  *Don't forget to go clear the file every once in a while...*  (:  Here it is:

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class Logger
{

    private static final String LOGTAG = "Logger";

    // Set to false to remove creation of local file
    private static final boolean IS_DEBUG_MODE = true;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" );

    public Logger() {

    }

    public static void d( String tag, String msg ) {
        Log.d( tag, msg );

        writeToFile( tag, msg );
    }

    public static void d( String tag, String msg, Throwable th ) {
        Log.d( tag, msg, th );

        writeToFile( tag, msg, th );
    }

    private static void writeToFile( String tag, String msg ) {

        if( IS_DEBUG_MODE ) {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File( root, "appLog.txt" );

            try {
                if( root.canWrite() ) {
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter( file, true );
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( fileWriter );

                    Date d = new Date();

                    out.write( mSDF.format( d ) + ": " + tag + " : " + msg );
                    out.newLine();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                Log.d( LOGTAG, "Couldn't write file: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile( String tag, String msg, Throwable th ) {
        writeToFile( tag, msg + ", e: " + th.getMessage() );
    }

}
```

Comment: well thanks! But this code have i to put inside my application code? Before the MainActivity?

Comment: Just put it in another class file, called Logger.java, with the same package declaration as your MainActivity.  Assuming your package is com.example.app then the first line will be `package com.example.app;` and the file will be located at the same level as your com.example.app.MainActivity file, ie. `src/com/example/app/Logger.java'.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you :D no more log problem.. But however my application crash! :( i think the swipe view code is the problem.

Comment: You're welcome!  Happy to help.  Have you put up another StackOverflow question regarding your application crash?

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

> There is a hidden service-menu where you can set loggin up. The
>   service-menu is started by "dialing" this phone number:
>       `*#*#2846579#*#*`

it worked for me.

http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/155/logcat-doesnt-show-messages-error-unable-to-open-log-device/

Comment: I don't believe this works any more (on Android 4.4.4, at least)  Can anyone else confirm that it does work?

Answer (score 0):

Dialing that phone number doesn't solve the problem.

Open a new command line (cmd) and write adb shell insmod /system/lib/modules/logger.ko

That it will solve the problem. (Samsung Galaxy i9070).